# Logic of my Stored Procedure, Loop cursors

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Let's see if i can make this clear. Basically what i want to do and i don't know how is this: inside my loop how can i iterate those 2 cursors?  After fetching those rows i want to insert in those 2 tables as you can see in the snippet :

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_docs

     IS

       dom_doc       DOM_DOCUMENT.DOMAIN_DOC%TYPE;
       type_doc_pk   TYPE_DOCS.TYPE_DOC_PK%TYPE;
       type_doc      TYPE_DOCS.TYPE_DOCUMENT%TYPE;
       user_code     TYPE_DOCS.USERCODE%TYPE;
       result_code   ECM_TIPO_DOCS.CODIGO_RESULTADO%TYPE;
       LS_LOCAL      INTEGER;
       l_id          INTEGER;

    cursor get_local
        is
        SELECT ls_local_pk FROM rt_local_ls

        rc_loc   c_loc%ROWTYPE;


cursor get_docs 
    is
    SELECT DOM_DOCUMENT.DOMAIN_DOC INTO dom_doc,
            TYPE_DOCS.TYPE_DOC_PK INTO type_doc_pk,
            TYPE_DOCS.TYPE_DOCUMENT INTO type_doc,
            TYPE_DOCS.USERCODE INTO user_code,
            TYPE_DOCS.CODE_RESULT INTO result_code
      FROM TYPE_DOCS 
        JOIN DOM_TDOC_SIS 
               ON TYPE_DOCS.TYPE_DOC_PK = DOM_TDOC_SIS.TYPE_DOC_PK
         JOIN DOM_DOCUMENT 
              ON DOM_TDOC_SIS.DOMAIN_DOC_PK = DOM_DOCUMENT.DOMAIN_DOC_PK
         WHERE DOM_DOCUMENT.DOMAIN_DOC_PK IN (2, 10) 
          AND NOT EXISTS
                 (
                  SELECT 1
                    FROM TP_DOC_MAP
                   WHERE  TP_DOC_MAP.LS_LOCAL_PK = LS_LOCAL        ----this is the variable that i have to iterate it's what i am getting from the other cursor
                          AND TP_DOC_MAP.LS_SYSTEM_PK = 3 
                         AND TP_DOC_MAP.ACTIVE = 1 
                         AND TP_DOC_MAP.CODE = TYPE_DOCS.TYPE_DOC_PK 
                );


BEGIN

    OPEN get_local;

    FETCH get_local INTO rc_loc

    IF get_local%FOUND
      THEN
           for md_local in get_local

           LOOP

           OPEN get_docs;

           FETCH get_docs INTO....


           ---now this is where i don't know how to do inside this loop i want to repeat the cursor get_docs  for each row in the cursor get_local
           --and then insert with the values fetched for each iteration


             INSERT INTO TP_DOC VALUES (  
              type_doc_pk,               
              type_doc,                     
              1,                    
              SYSDATE,             
              NULL)
              RETURNING id INTO l_id;


              INSERT INTO TP_DOC_MAP VALUES (
              l_id,
              LS_LOCAL,
              3,
              type_doc_pk,
              1,
              sysdate,
              NULL
              );


          END LOOP


      END IF;

END add_docs;
```

how can i do this? for each LS_LOCAL that exists it will have to run the sele

for each LS_LOCAL that exists, it will have to run the select in the cursor get_docs with the LS_LOCAL variable.

Comment: Don't you think you could simplify your question (and therefore, be more clear for all of us that don't know your data) removing the useless information from yor code? Then we can focus on iterate 2 cursors.

Answer (score 1):

Embedded cursor FOR loops are one option. Here's how (I removed irrelevant parts of code to make it as simple as possible):

```
begin
  for cur_l in (select ls_local_pk from rt_local_ls) 
  loop
    for cur_d in (select domain_doc, 
                         type_doc_pk, ...
                  from type_docs join dom_tdoc_sis ...
                 )
    loop
      insert into tp_doc ...
      insert into tp_doc_map ...
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: so i don't have to declare those cursors in that way? and i assume that i can easily do some validations inside those for loops. For exampe before the loop for cur_d , i can use some validations: IF get_local%FOUND
      THEN....

Comment: You could have declared them explicitly, but that requires you to open a cursor, create a loop, take care about exiting, close the cursor ... not that it *can't* be done, but this way is simpler as Oracle handles most of those things for you. As of validations: certainly, do whatever you want between two FOR statements; they don't have to follow one another immediately.